# Render HTML divs that have a function dynamically with EJS and Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dynamic, ejs

I am trying to render a relatively simple scoreboard dynamically with EJS on a website. I have a working setup for a single player which I would like to render for X amount of players. I have the start setup working for however many players you choose but the functionality only works for the first player. A summary:

- You have a score "field" which is an input + a button that says "add".
- I specifically chose the text input that I later convert to a Number because the number input has these arrows next to the input which are ugly.
- The function works so that it removes the 'add' button from after the first input and adds it to the current input.
- These inputs represent 'rounds' in a game where you get a score. Basically you fill in your score for the round and move on to the next round.

All of this is working smoothly but when I try to render the full design + function *per player* it becomes a mess. The second/third/fourth player render their start position perfectly but when I press the "add" button on their score-field it changes the first player's score field. This is obviously because I am not naming/id'ing/class'ing the new elements right. They all point to player 1. I just can't seem to figure out where to put the forEach (and where to close it) and how to name these elements so that it works! How do I get the same functionality for each player? Should I create a class "Class Scoreboard" with getters and setters (if so: any tips?) or can I wiggle my way out of this with some more DOM manipulation?

**pre-load choice page**

```
    <h3>How many players are playing?</h3>
    <form id="preloadForm" action="/preload" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">
        <input type="number" name="numberOfPlayers">

        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit" name="playButton">PLAY!</button>
    </form>
```

**actual index page (w/ br and closing tags removed)**

```
    <div class="all-players">
        <% players.forEach(player => { %>
        <div id="player<%= parseInt(players[player]) + 1 %>" class="single-player">
            <strong>Player <%= parseInt(players[player]) + 1 %> </strong>

            <label for="score">Note Your Scores Here:</label>

            <div id="scoreTable">
                <div id="parent<%= players[player] %>">
                    <input type="text" class="scoreContainer">
                    <button id="child<%= players[player] %>" onclick="addInputButton()">Add</button>

                </div>
                <span id="newElement"></span>

            </div>

            <button onclick="calculateScore()">Calculate Your Result</button>

            <span id="finalScore"></span>

            <% }); %>

            <script>
                function addInputButton() {

                    //Create an input type dynamically.
                    let newInput = document.createElement("input");
                    let newButton = document.createElement("button")
                    let lineBreak = document.createElement("br");
                    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    let space = document.createTextNode(" ");

                    //Assign different attributes to the element.
                    newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
                    newInput.setAttribute("class", "scoreContainer");

                    newButton.setAttribute("onclick", "addInputButton()");
                    newButton.setAttribute("id", "child");
                    newButton.innerHTML = "Add";

                    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "parent")

                    var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
                    var child = document.getElementById("child");
                    var addElement = document.getElementById("newElement");

                    parent.removeChild(child);
                    parent.removeAttribute("id", "parent");

                    //Append the element in div, then add div to span.
                    addElement.appendChild(newDiv);

                    newDiv.appendChild(newInput);
                    newDiv.appendChild(space);
                    newDiv.appendChild(newButton);
                    newDiv.appendChild(lineBreak);
                };

                function calculateScore() {
                    let scores = document.getElementsByClassName("scoreContainer");
                    let answerAsNumber = 0;

                    for (let i = 0; i < scores.length - 1; i++) {
                        answerAsNumber += parseInt(scores[i].value, 10);
                    }

                    let answerAsText = answerAsNumber.toString();

                    let scoreLineBreak = document.createElement("br");
                    let finalScoreDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    let scoreText = document.createTextNode(answerAsText);

                    finalScoreDiv.setAttribute("class", "finalScoreDiv");

                    var answerElement = document.getElementById("finalScore");

                    answerElement.appendChild(scoreLineBreak);
                    answerElement.appendChild(finalScoreDiv);
                    finalScoreDiv.appendChild(scoreText);
                };
```

**server side Node.js**

```
app.get('/preload', (req, res) => {
    res.render('preload');
});

app.post('/preload', (req, res) => {

    let numberOfPlayers = req.body.numberOfPlayers;
    let playerObj = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){
        playerObj[i] = i;
    };

    let playerArr = Object.keys(playerObj);

    res.render('index', { players: playerArr });
});
```

QUESTION: How do I render this functionality per player, depending on the preload choice?